# how to slide the slides in bxslider using mouse drag

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

I want to slide left or right the slides in bx slider using mouse drag. Is there any way I can do it?
on dragging left or right with mouse the slide should move in left or right direction.

```
<div class="slide-two hp-rtwo">
  <ul class="trending-products" style="cursor:-webkit-grab;-webkit-transform:translateX(0);">
    <li>
      <img src="../images/postad.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="../images/postad.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="../images/postad.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="../images/postad.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="../images/postad.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="../images/postad.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true
    });
    $('.trending-products').bxSlider({
        auto: false,
        minSlides: 4,
        maxSlides: 20,
        slideWidth: 250,
        slideMargin: 20,
        controls: true,
        moveSlides: 1,
        pager: false,
    });
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

i did it like this ->

It needs to include jquery-ui bundle

html code

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="dragg-wrap"></div>
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
            <!--slide content goes here-->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css code for .dragg-wrap

```
.dragg-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor: grabbing;
}
```

javascript code

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    controls: false,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
});


var sliderdiv = $('.slider .dragg-wrap');

sliderdiv.draggable({ 
    axis: "x" ,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.position);
      $('.bx-wrapper ul.bxslider').css('left', ui.position.left);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $('.bx-wrapper ul.bxslider').css('left', '0px');
      if (ui.position.left > 0 ) {
        slider.goToNextSlide();
      }
      else {
        slider.goToPrevSlide();
      }
     $('.slider .dragg-wrap').css('left', '0px');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes my frient you can use jQuery Draggable in Jquery UI
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Isn't there any other method like using css transformation etc. ?

Comment: No my friend you need to track the mouse events for the purpose and then change the css accordingly mousedown and mouseleave events. The task can be done with jQuery manually also but this plugin is really handy and easy to use.

Comment: I want to slide the element left and right only so are there some option in this jquery drag api to make it left and right only ?

Comment: I can not mark it as an answer because its not working as I expected but thanks anyway